Python lichess получение партий за определённый период
import berserk
import datetime

session = berserk.TokenSession("token")
client = berserk.Client(session=session)

end_date = datetime.datetime.now()
start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(days=31)

user_games = client.games.export_by_player(
    username="username", 
    since=start_date.timestamp(), 
    until=end_date.timestamp(), 
    as_pgn="true")

with open("user_games.pgn", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for game in user_games:
        file.write(game)

Помогите, в user_games.pgn сохраняется все партии пользователя. А хотелось только в заданом промежутке времени(1 месяц)
